# ROS Wiki: Node Information not shown

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I edited the ROS wiki about [elas_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/elas_ros), where I added a link to the source code on github. But after this change the information about which topic the nodes subscribe to and what they publish (which would be under "3. Nodes") is not visible anymore. When editing the text, the text is there, but not when it is displayed as a normal wiki page. What might be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261466/ros-wiki:-node-information-not-shown/) by [sihe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30331/sihe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've [added a fix](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/elas_ros?action=info).

```
{{{#!clearsilver CS/NodeAPI
```

Seems like a new line is needed after the curly brace.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sihe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30331/sihe/) on 2017-05-11**:
Great, thank you!